# discord.py bot only responds to one command

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, bots, discord.py

It only displays one of the commands at one given time.
If I write `!hi` or `!bye` it won't work, but if I write `!sing` it would output `la la la`.
If I switch the character before it, it would change to
`!hi` or `!sing` not working
but `!bye` working and saying `Goodbye!`

````
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
  .format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('!hi'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('!bye'):
    await message.channel.send('Goodbye Friend!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('!sing'):
    await message.channel.send('la la la')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))```
````

Answer (score 2):

Only have one event, don't make a new one for every command.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  elif message.content.startswith('!sing'):
    await message.channel.send('La La la.')
  elif message.content.startswith('!hi'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use multiple events, instead use all of the events in one event like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('!hi'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
 
  elif message.content.startswith('!bye'):
    await message.channel.send('Goodbye Friend!')

  elif message.content.startswith('!sing'):
    await message.channel.send('la la la')
```

Also, make sure to have `elif` in the other events instead of `if`.
This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat on_message events. Have only one and put if statements into this one event.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of using `commands.Bot()`:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

@bot.command()
async def sing(ctx):
    await ctx.send("la la la!")

@bot.command()
async def bye(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Goodbye friend!")
```

`Bot()` inherits from `Client()`, and provides much more functionality when it comes to handling commands!

---

### References:

- [`commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot)